# Doctrine: Creating schema (Unknown Entity namespace alias 'C'.)

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am very new to ORM and Doctrine so please be patient with me.

I am more or less following the getting started tutorial now (just with different tables to make it more interesting). I have created two YAML files defining my schema which is very simple:

User:

```
User:
  type: entity
  table: users
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: AUTO
  fields:
    firstName:
      type: string
    lastName:
      type: string
    birthdate:
      type: datetime
    email:
      type: string
    username:
      type: string
    password:
      type: string
  oneToMany:
    pages:
      targetEntity: Page
      mappedBy: user
```

Page:

```
Page:
  type: entity
  table: pages
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
    content:
      type: text
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: pages
```

Now I am trying to use the SchemaTool to create a database schema. When I run this code:

```
$em = Zend_Registry::get('entityManager');
$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
$classes = array(
    $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\User'),
    $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Page')
);
```

I get this error:

```
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Doctrine\ORM\Configuration.php(150):
Doctrine\ORM\ORMException::unknownEntityNamespace('C')
#1
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(155):
Doctrine\ORM\Configuration->getEntityNamespace('C')
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(247):
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#3
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\application\modules\default\controllers\DoctrineUtilController.php(16):
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513):
DoctrineUtilController->generateModelsAction()
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295):
Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('generateModelsA...')
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\application\Bootstrap.php(177):
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\library\Zend\Application.php(366):
Bootstrap->run()
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zend\public\index.php(54): Zend_Application->run()
#10 {main}    
    $tool->createSchema($classes);
```

Any ideas where could be a problem?

---

Additional information just in case. This is how I create entity manager in the Bootstrap.php file:

```
protected function _initDoctrine() {
    // (1)
    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

    // Proxy Configuration (2)
    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH.'/proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Application\Proxies');
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(('development' === APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT));

    // Mapping Configuration (3)
    $driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/mappings/yml');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

    // Caching Configuration (4)
    if ('development' === APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT) {
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
    } else {
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
    }
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // database configuration parameters (5)
    $conn = array(
        'driver' => $this->configuration->database->adapter,
        'user' => $this->configuration->database->username,
        'password' => $this->configuration->database->password,
        'dbname' => $this->configuration->database->dbname
    );

    // obtaining the entity manager (6)
    $evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();
    $this->entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config, $evm);
    Zend_Registry::set('entityManager', $this->entityManager);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem with the path definitions.

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
```

This shouldn't be the absolute path, as Doctrine assumes that is the class name with namespace, so it takes that 'C:\' as namespace.

So it is a problem with configuration or autoloaders.

There is a sandbox in the Doctrine which includes a basic working configuration, you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: @Hakan Deryal There is no sandbox for Doctrine 2 yet, only for version 1.2 so I cannot do that. I set up my autoloaders and configurations according to this tutorial: http://snipplr.com/view/38628/integrating-zend-framework-110-with-doctrine-2-using-doctrines-autoloader/

Comment: I don't know anything about the framework, so can't comment on the guide. But the errors indicate that problem I mentioned. And there is a sandbox for Doctrine2. In git repo, under tools directory.

Comment: Well, I can't find any link to the sandbox on Doctrine website.

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html#sandbox-quickstart Its only in the github repo for now it seems.

Comment: @Hakan Deryal Well, and the sandbox I have downloaded from the github is not working (there are some files missing) so that's just great.

Comment: Thats strange. It works perfectly for me. Can you post the errors? Maybe its a PHP configuration issue, I'm not sure.